# Form Table Data to JSON string

Tags: jquery, json

I have a form that has a table with inputs and I need to properly convert it into json array per row. Example:

```
Id    Name     Gender
1     John     Male
2     Rose     Female

Desired output:
[
  { Id:1, Name: "John", Gender: "Male" },
  { Id:2, Name: "Rose", Gender: "Female" }
]
```

Please help me. I use this code

```
JSON.stringify($('#myform').serializeArray());
```

But it gives me this output:

```
[
  {\"name\":\"Id\",\"value\":\"1\"},
  {\"name\":\"Name\",\"value\":\"John\"},
  {\"name\":\"Gender\",\"value\":\"Male\"}
]
```

See it in action: https://jsfiddle.net/srssnzj8/2/

Comment: Please add your actual HTML to the question.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan hi this is the fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/srssnzj8/2/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To do what you require you can use `map()` to create an array of the values of the `input` and `select` elements within each `tr`. Try this:

```js
$(document).on('click', '#save', function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var data = $('tr').map(function() {
     var obj = {};
     $(this).find('input, select').each(function() {
         obj[this.name] = $(this).val();
        });
        return obj;
    }).get();
    
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="#" id="myForm">
    <table>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>1</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="1" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name" value="John" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="Gender">
                    <option value="Male" selected>Male</option>
                    <option value="Female">Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <span>2</span>
                <input type="hidden" name="Id" value="2" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <input type="text" name="Name" value="Rose" />
            </td>
            <td>
                <select class="form-control" name="Gender">
                    <option value="Male">Male</option>
                    <option value="Female" selected>Female</option>
                </select>
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <button type="submit" id="save">
        Submit
    </button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically you have to

- Use `$("tbody tr").each(...` to iterate through all rows
- Use `$(this).find("td");` to get all row's cells
- Use `$cells.each(...` to iterate through all cells and `$(this).find("input").val()` to get the texts.
- Store them in an array and simply call `JSON.stringify`for it

Also changed the html a bit, adding `thead`, `tbody` and `th`, see your updated [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/srssnzj8/3/)

Answer (score 0):

You have to iterate through each table row and for each input on the row map name to value

```
function getFormData(){
  var rowData = [];
  $("tr").each(function() {
    var unindexed_array= jQuery(this).find("input, select").serializeArray();
    var obj= {};
    jQuery(unindexed_array).each(function(){
       obj[this.name] = this.value;
    });
     rowData .push(obj);
});    
   return rowData ;
}
```

Comment: Downvoted because of confusing naming. Please don't call objects arrays. Also you're using the `map()` function wrong. Either return the new element in each iteration or use `forEach()`.